# qsort dynamic 2d char array with alphanumeric filenames - C program

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, alphanumeric, qsort

I'm new here, so this is my first post. I've been struggling for 2 weeks to solve this problem. I'm trying to open a directory, capture and store the names of the files found, sort them in ascending order, and print the results. My issue is either qsort causes my program to crash entirely, or qsort doesn't sort the array at all because the files are alphanumeric. I even tried looping through a stored filename to output each character, just to see if I could eventually try comparing the characters between two array locations for sorting. But I noticed that it can't seem to see or recognize the numbers in the alphanumeric filename (for example: "f1.jpg" will only print "f", a blank, then "j", and that's it. I should note that I cannot change the file names because I don't know in advance the names or total files. I'm trying to make this to be dynamic. The following is the main code that I'm having problems with since it crashes at the 'qsort' keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b);
void readInFilenames();

int main
{
   readInFilenames();
   system("pause");
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

void readInFilenames()
{
  char cwd[1024];
  DIR *dir = NULL;
  struct dirent *pent = NULL;
  struct stat info;
  char file_path[50] = "files/";
  int total_files = 0;
  int file_size;

  // Change directory to file location
  chdir(file_path);

  if((getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))) != NULL)
  {
    printf("Current Directory: %s\n", cwd);
  }

  // Open directory and count the total number of files found
  dir = opendir(cwd);

  if(dir != NULL)
  {
    while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(stat(pent->d_name, &info))
        {
            printf("ERROR: stat%s: %s\n", pent->d_name, strerror(errno));
        }
        else
        {
            if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
            {
                if((strcmp(pent->d_name, ".cproject") == 0) || (strcmp(pent->d_name, ".project") == 0))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    total_files++;
                    file_size = sizeof(pent->d_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("# of files found: %d\n", total_files);
    rewinddir(dir);    //reset pointer back to beginning of file directory

    // Create character array to store file names;
    char *filenames_arr[total_files][file_size];
    int size = sizeof(filenames_arr)/sizeof(filenames_arr[total_files]);

    total_files = 0;   //reset file counter back to 0;

    // Read and store file names in the character array
    while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(stat(pent->d_name, &info))
        {
            printf("ERROR: stat%s: %s\n", pent->d_name, strerror(errno));
        }
        else
        {
            if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
            {
                if((strcmp(pent->d_name, ".cproject") == 0) || (strcmp(pent->d_name, ".project") == 0))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(filenames_arr[total_files], pent->d_name);
                    //printf("%s\n", filenames_arr[i]);
                    total_files++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    // Print original array contents
    printf("Original List of Files\n");
    printf("----------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < total_files; i++)
    {
      printf("%s\n", filenames_arr[i]);
    }

    // Sort array in ascending order
    qsort(filenames_arr, total_files, size, compare);
    //qsort(filenames_arr, total_files, sizeof(filenames_arr[0]), (char (*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);

    // Print organized array contents
    printf("Sorted List of Files\n");
    printf("----------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < total_files; i++)
    {
      printf("%s\n", filenames_arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nFinished!\n");
  }
}
```

This portion of code is when I was trying to print each individual characters. This was originally located where the final array printing takes place in the previous code:

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < total_files)
    {
        printf("File Name: %s\n", filenames_arr[i]);
        printf("String Length: %d\n", strlen(filenames_arr[i]));
        while(filenames_arr[i] != '\0')
        {
            printf("Checking filenames_arr[%d][%d]\n", i, j);

            if(isalpha((unsigned char)filenames_arr[i][j]) != 0)
            {
                printf("In isalpha\n");
                printf("Found: %c\n", filenames_arr[i][j]);
            }
            else if(isdigit((unsigned char)filenames_arr[i][j]) != 0)
            {
                printf("In isdigit\n");
                printf("Found: %d\n", filenames_arr[i][j]);
            }
            j++;
        }
        printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
```

How do I sort a 2D array of alphanumeric character strings using qsort? What is it about qsort, or even my array setup that's causing my program to crash? Also, how does qsort work? I've tried searching forums and online course notes to find out whether or not qsort only sorts by looking just at the first character, all characters, or if it has problems with numbers. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I made the following edits to my code. Its working much better, in that `qsort` no longer crashes program. But, `qsort` still isn't sorting. Here are the updates I made, followed by a screenshot of the results:

```
typedef struct{
  char *filename;
}filedata;

int compare(const void *a, const void *b);
void readInFilenames();

int main(void){
  readInFilenames();
  system("pause");
}

int compare (const void *a, const void *b ) {
  filedata *ia = (filedata *)a;
  filedata *ib = (filedata *)b;
  return strcmp(ia->filename, ib->filename);
}

readInFilenames(){
.
.
.
  printf("# of files found: %d\n", total_files);
  rewinddir(dir);

  filedata fn_data[total_files];
  total_files = 0;

  printf("Original Array: \n");
  while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    if((strcmp(pent->d_name, ".cproject") == 0) || (strcmp(pent->d_name, ".project") == 0))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        fn_data[total_files].filename = malloc(file_size + 1);
        strcpy(fn_data[total_files].filename, pent->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", fn_data[total_files].filename);
        total_files++;
    }
  }
  closedir(dir);

  printf("\n");
  qsort(fn_data, total_files, sizeof(filedata), compare);

  printf("Sorted Array:\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < total_files; i++)
    printf("%s\n", fn_data[i].filename);

  printf("Finished!\n");
}
```

[Click here to see sorting results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbEeu.jpg)

The list should print: f0.dat, f1.dat, f2.dat, f3.dat,...,f20.dat. But instead it prints: f0.dat, f1.dat, f10.dat, f11.dat,...,f9.dat.

Comment: `filenames_arr` is an "array `total_files` of array `file_size` of pointer to char".  Each element of the array is an "array `file_size` of pointer to char".  2 addresses of that element are  passed to `qsort()`.  They are not of the type `(char **)` but "pointer to array `file_size` of pointer to char".  Type mis-match.

Comment: `strcpy(filenames_arr[total_files], pent->d_name);` should  generate a warning due to type mis-match.  Save time: enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Can you redefine the filenames_arr using a struct filedata with members such as char *filename? You can then create a struct filedata fn_data[total_files] and you will still need to malloc each fn_data.filename to be file_size in length. I usually call qsort this way because everything is linearly packed together, for it to work with. qsort(fn_data, total_files, sizeof(struct filedata), compare); The compare function can look into the passed data it gets and follow any pointers as needed, but then upon completion the outer qsort call will reorganize each unit of data to keep it packed linearly

Comment: @chux : you're right, with your second comment. I couldn't figure out how to resolve this warning with the `strcpy` mismatch. I used @Snohdo comment suggestion and re-structured my code a bit, which helped resolve the warnings and errors. Given the suggestions, `qsort` no longer crashes my program because @chux first suggestion was correct about the mismatched pointer array. But, it still isn't sorting the files. I will update my original post to show the edits and results.

Comment: @N.Adams Tip: Instead of conditionally `file_size = sizeof(pent->d_name);`, use `int file_size = sizeof(pent->d_name)`.  This avoids `char *filenames_arr[total_files][file_size];` occurring with an uninitialized value in `file_size`

Comment: @N.Adams Advanced idea: Robust code would not rely on the 2nd pass of `while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)` producing the same as the first pass.

Comment: @N.Adams `fn_data[total_files].filename = malloc(file_size + 1);` is borderline.  Code does not certainly have a valid value in `file_size`.  IAC, `file_size` is not needed with the update.  Could use `fn_data[total_files].filename = strdup(pent->d_name);` to allocate and copy the _string_.  Note: `qsort(fn_data, total_files, sizeof(filedata), compare);` is OK, `qsort(fn_data, total_files, sizeof fn_data[0], compare);` is better.

Comment: @chux `int file_size` is setup at the top of the function because I'm using it throughout just that function. When I do `file_size = sizeof(pent->d_name)` its getting initialized with the correct size. Also, the first pass with `while((pent = readdir(dir))` is used to count the number of files found in a directory, and separate out the files it found, & not count any sub-directories or the ".cproject" or ".project" files. That's how I get the total to use for the `fn_data[total_files]` array. The 2nd pass is to then go back & read in just the files I want to store. I will try the `strdup` now.

Comment: @chux i'm going to comment out the `file_size = sizeof(pent->d_name)` because I'm getting a warning at the moment that i'm setting it but not using it (which at the moment is true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has fixed code to cope with "qsort dynamic 2d char array with filenames" by enabling warnings and using [@Snohdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934094/qsort-dynamic-2d-char-array-with-alphanumeric-filenames-c-program?noredirect=1#comment84878093_48934094) advice.

Yet code is still doing a compare with `strcmp()` which only treat digits as characters and not numerically to achieve `f1.dat, f2.dat, f3.dat,...,f20.dat` order.

---

Following is a compare functions that looks for digits to invoke an alternate compare for numeric sub-strings.  Variations on this compare can be made by OP to suit detailed coding goals.

```
int AdamsOrder(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  // Compare as `unsigned char` as that is `strcmp()` behavior.  C11 7.24.1 3
  const unsigned char *us1 = (const unsigned char *) s1;
  const unsigned char *us2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;
  while (*us1 && *us2) {
    if (isdigit(*us1) && isdigit(*us2)) {
      char *end;  // dummy
      unsigned long long l1 = strtoull(us1, &end, 10);  // Parse for a number
      unsigned long long l2 = strtoull(us2, &end, 10);
      if (l1 > l2) return 1;
      if (l1 < l2) return -1;
      // Continue on treating as text. OP needs to decide how to handle ties: "0001" vs "1"
    }
    if (*us1 > *us2) return 1;
    if (*us1 < *us2) return -1;
    us1++;
    us2++;
  }
  // At this point, at least one string ended (i.e. points to '\0').
  // The return statement below will behave as follows:
  // If a string ended, *us1/2 will be 0. Let an unfinished one be X > 0.
  // First string ended : ( 0 > X ) - ( 0 < X ) = false - true  = 0 - 1 = -1
  // Second string ended: ( X > 0 ) - ( X < 0 ) = true  - false = 1 - 0 =  1
  // Both strings ended : ( 0 > 0 ) - ( 0 < 0 ) = false - false = 0 - 0 =  0      
  return (*us1 > *us2) - (*us1 < *us2);
}
```

Comment: I tried the code, and replaced the `strcmp` in the `compare` function with `AdamsOrder`. It didn't crash, but it got stuck in an infinite loop. I'm wondering where in the code it stops and hangs up. Maybe I will try with 5 files, and see if it happens again, or if it completes the sorting process.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That worked perfectly. I, also, accepted the answer :)

Comment: @chux This helped a lot (I added code to handle ties but otherwise used almost the same code). I added some explanation on the not too obvious last return statement. Would be nice if you could validate my comments and adapt them if they are wrong.

Comment: @TimMeyer Edit is OK.  Note that `(a > b) - (b < a)` is a common idiom in robust `fcmp()` functions.